# Can't find the right plug from my PSU to my raptor 10K drive

Tags: hard-drive, installation, power-supply

I have a corsair tx 750 PSU, and I can't seem to find the correct plug that would fit into the cable for my raptor 10K 300 gb drive.

arghh.

**Update**
My raptor was OEM, and didn't come with any cables.

I have this cable that on one end has 2 serial ATA connectors, and the other end just says 1234 (it has 4 female rounded holes in it).

Comment: One end of that cable should be attached to your PSU.  On the other end you use the either the flat style plug shown below, or the 4 rounded holes plug to plug into your hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it look like this would fit it?

[image]

If so, you can buy an adapter [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812104652).

Comment: my cable is all black, but one end has 2 of those on it (like your pic), and the other has 4 large holes (female) that need a male connector (like the pic at new egg).

Comment: and yes that would fit just fine, just don't have it!

Comment: So follow the link at the bottom and buy one.

Comment: nah, i'll just go to my local store in the morning, I can't wait.

Comment: @homestead, every picture I've seen of the 750TX has one of those connectors on a wire coming out of the PSU.  If yours doesn't, you have a real anomaly on your hands.

Comment: hyperslug, the picture in the above answer, I have that connector. It goes into the raptor just fine, but the other end of the connector doesn't fit into my PSU.

Answer (score 1):

One cable should be a power connector that goes from Raptor to PSU that has a wire sequence of yellow, black, black, red.  I just found out that the Raptor has both a SATA and an old molex type connector, so choose one but not both.  Again only 1 power wire should go from drive to PSU.

Another cable is a thin flat SATA cable that plugs into the motherboard.